# ArcGIS connect to common data and defining styles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-database, template

I am trying to set up a template .mxd which will be the basis for all of our project mapping (i.e. each new project begins with a copy of this template which is then renamed).  All of the project data within this .mxd will be stored in a single project specific geodatabase (which will be stored along with the template and renamed).

The reason for this template is that I want to standardise styles, labels etc across all projects.

Within the .mxd there will also be a lot of, what I would call, common data (i.e. contours, tennement boundaries, landmakrs, towns, roads etc) which do not change from project to project.

Rather than storing all of this common data in the project geodatabase is there a way to store it in a separate geodatabase and then link/reference this in the template .mxd?  i.e. link to a common/central source?

When connecting to this external source however I would like it to also pull in the preset styles and labels into the .mxd rather than defaulting to whatever ArcGIS feels like.

I am concerned that everytime I create a new project I am duplicating a lot of data which is taking up a relatively large amount of space but this is much quicker than going through each sub-set of common data and redefining the styles each time.

I feel that there is probably a way to do this but I haven't come across it yet.

ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the "common" data is stored right now, so will assume it is in a format that can be read by ArcGIS Desktop.

A .mxd basically store paths to data sources and draw them on the screen.

So you could have a Geodatabase with common data and a Geodatabase for each project.

(Update) ESRI has the .lyr file that stores the path to the source and also the symbology. The symbology will be the same for everyone using the .lyr file.

You could also save the symbology, give it a name and categorize them. Search for Style Manager.

You could also, in the template you want to make, load all the layers you want, with the symbology you want, and just hide/show them when needed.

Comment: OK I relised that I missed out a fundamental part of my question - the part to do with styles.  I have updated the original question to reflect this.  Your answer does help with the first part however.  I will move the feature dataset for common data into it's own geodatabase.  Any suggestions for the updated question?